# How do you compare two object values in two separate arrays using Javascript (JS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

Lets says I have two arrays that are filled with objects, that have multiple properties, with some keys that are the same.

```
        var array1 = [
          {name: "Jim", city: 'Toronto', id:'1281732'},
          {name: "Alex", city: 'New York', id:'32423'},
          {name: "Simon", city: 'San Francisco', id:'234234'},
          {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee', id:'1282342341732'}
        ]

        var array2 = [
          {name: "Joey", city: 'Raleigh'},
          {name: "Alex", city: 'New York'},
          {name: "Lee", city: 'San Diego'},
          {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee'}
        ]
```

How can I find that the 2nd and 4th object in array1 are also found in array2 by comparing both the name and city. Meaning both object keys must match, and then take the duplicated object from array1 and push into a new array.

Using something like lodash or underscores is acceptable.

Comment: Please try a solution before asking how to do it. This is not a coding as a service platform.

Comment: Yes I am agree with @WilomGfx. Nested loop is the hint that you might try first.

Answer (score 1):

As in all programming tasks, what you do is think through the problem and come up with a solution that makes sense. In this case, searching the second array for each item in the first array can be done by iterating the first array, and on each iteration, iterating the second array until a match is found.

```js
var array1 = [
  {name: "Jim", city: 'Toronto', id:'1281732'},
  {name: "Alex", city: 'New York', id:'32423'},
  {name: "Simon", city: 'San Francisco', id:'234234'},
  {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee', id:'1282342341732'}
]

var array2 = [
  {name: "Joey", city: 'Raleigh'},
  {name: "Alex", city: 'New York'},
  {name: "Lee", city: 'San Diego'},
  {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee'}
]

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    if (array1[i].name == array2[j].name &&
        array1[i].city == array2[j].city) {
      result.push(array1[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

---

Modern syntax cleans it up some.

```js
var array1 = [
  {name: "Jim", city: 'Toronto', id:'1281732'},
  {name: "Alex", city: 'New York', id:'32423'},
  {name: "Simon", city: 'San Francisco', id:'234234'},
  {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee', id:'1282342341732'}
]

var array2 = [
  {name: "Joey", city: 'Raleigh'},
  {name: "Alex", city: 'New York'},
  {name: "Lee", city: 'San Diego'},
  {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee'}
]

var result = array1.filter(({name, city}) =>
  array2.some(o => o.name == name && o.city == city)
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the results which are in both arrays you can also simply use `filter()` function

```js
 var array1 = [
          {name: "Jim", city: 'Toronto', id:'1281732'},
          {name: "Alex", city: 'New York', id:'32423'},
          {name: "Simon", city: 'San Francisco', id:'234234'},
          {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee', id:'1282342341732'}
        ]

        var array2 = [
          {name: "Joey", city: 'Raleigh'},
          {name: "Alex", city: 'New York'},
          {name: "Lee", city: 'San Diego'},
          {name: "Jake", city: 'Milwaukee'}
        ]
        
 var array3 = array1.filter(row1 => array2.filter(row2 => row1.name == row2.name && row1.city == row2.city).length > 0);

console.log(array3);
```